# Verb for - “to go into”

Tags: motion-verbs

I wish to say - “I want to go into the deep forest and live with the bears.” Using online translation, I get - “Я хочу уйти в глубокий лес и жить с медведями”. However, from the dictionary:

уйти - to go from, to leave, to depart
пойти - to go (perfective)
войти - to go in, to enter

Hence, would the correct translation actually be “Я хочу войти/пойти в глубокий лес и жить с медведями”? Or is there a specific verb in Russian that translates as “to go into “?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing with translation is that you don't translate words, you translate texts. Languages don't always have a one-to-one mapping between words and idioms, your excerpt being an example of this.

Your translation is not that bad, it's grammatical and makes sense. The meaning of *уйти в* here is "to retire for, to retreat into", something you say when you remove yourself from your usual routine, either temporarily or for good. It is used in sentences like *уйти в монастырь* "join the monastery", *уйти в работу* "immerse oneself into work", *уйти в запой* "go on a binge drinking episode" etc.

*Пойти* would make some sense too, although *пойти* means "to go to, to take a walk to", it does not convey the same meaning of excluding yourself from your everyday life.

*Войти* means "enter", it does not really work here.

I would translate your sentence this way:

> Мне хочется забраться поглубже в лес и жить там c медведями

*Забраться* means "to get somewhere through some effort":

> - Есть просто задача: забраться на гору и прыгнуть с матерчатыми крыльями
> - Конечно, меня тянуло забраться поближе к Сердоликовой бухте
> - Для того, чтобы в Израиле выпить настоящий кофе, надо забраться в шатер к бедуинам, а ни в первый мой приезд туда, ни во второй мне этого не удалось

*Поглубже* is an example of using the prefixed comparativе (*приставочная сравнительная степень*) of an adjective to convey the meaning of "very, really":

> - Для полного спокойствия выберите пароль подлиннее (*= очень длинный*)
> - Тем временем у входа на телевидение ассистенты суетились, отбирая из многотысячной толпы рожи пострашнее (*= очень страшные*)
> - Позвонил куда-то и приказал принести чаю покрепче (*= очень крепкого*)

Answer (score 5):

“I want to go into the deep forest and live with the bears.”

The point is that the meaning of the sentence is not a simple promenade, but a change of the way of life. So you actually are going to leave this everyday life of yours or leave for the forest. And here the translation

Я хочу уйти подальше в лес и жить среди медведей

seems to be more suitable. Пойти, to my mind, presupposes вернуться, to come back, and does not look like a serious intention.